# How to combine different data sets in Pandas (python 3)?

Tags: python, pandas

My problem revolves around using the groupby function in pandas and trying to combine two data sets.

Right now my data looks like this:

```
Name     Price
James    2
Jon      3 
James    0
Bob      4
Bob      0
```

**What I need is** to create a data set that contains THREE metrics: the sum of Price for each Name, the count of the number instances where Price is Zero for each name, and the count of times each name appears..

So ideally the output would look like this

```
Name     Price   Count of Frequency      Count of Zero
James    2             2                       1
Jon      3             1                       0
Bob      4             1                       1
```

Right now my code looks this like:

```
newlist = df1.join(s)
countif = newlist.groupby(['KW']).size().reset_index()
group = newlist.groupby(['KW'])
sumif = group.sum().reset_index()
zero = newlist[newlist['Price'] == 0.0]
zero2 = zero.groupby(['KW']).size().reset_index()
concat = pd.concat([sumif,countif,zero2], axis=1)
```

But this has a number of drawbacks: its unpythonic and inefficient, it creates duplicate rows of the KW column, and it does not line up all the data in a uniform way because when the "zero2" variable only shows those KW where the price is 0 so I get something like this:

```
 KW      Price      KW       0      KW       0
 James    2         james    2      James    1
 Bob      4         Bob      2      Bob      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a groupby with an apply.

```
def func(x):
    return pd.Series({'Obs': len(x)
                    , 'Sum': x.price.sum()
                    , 'Zeros': len(x[x.price==0])})
```

Usage:

```
df.groupby(["name"]).apply(func)
```

Comment: Hi zerovector,  I am getting an error when I try to apply that idea:     def func(x):
    return pd.Series({'Obs': len(x),'Sum': sum(x),'Zeros': len(x[x.price==0])}) -- the error says: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry about that.  Should be x.sum() instead of sum(x).  I'll edit my original answer as well

Comment: this is a simple question that is escaping me -- for the last part: len(x[x.price==0])}), the column is actually called price. -- however, when i type in len(x[x.price.==0])}), python does not like the syntax -- do you know of a simple way to get tell python not to read the period?  Sorry I know this is off topic!

Comment: Personally, I would rename the column to remove the period.  You could try x["price."] but that might not work either.

Comment: Thank you zerovector -- your help put me on the right path to solve the problem!  An apply function was what I was looking for!